# How to update Entity Framework Core after adding a new table to the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db?toc=/aspnet/core/toc.json&bc=/aspnet/core/breadcrumb/toc.json&view=aspnetcore-2.2

I have followed this instruction above and it works. I have the database and the C# code.

The next phase is that I add a new table named test

- Table: test
- Columns: Testid (int), testname (nvarchar(50))

This test table is added in the database.

The code

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

enables you to create the class and its data member from scratch but this time I have added a new table.

The code

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

does not work in relation to maintenance when I have added a new table.

The main question:

What code in PowerShell or something similar should I use in order to update the current C# code in relation to Entity Framework Core?

I need to have c# code for the table "Test" in VS solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Specify -Force to recreate the files

Comment: Do you mean "add-Force makePostTabale" or another code in the package manager console?

Comment: No, just -Force - read the docs !

Comment: Can't find info about "-Force" when googling, do you have a link to "-force" for detailed documentation? Thank you!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext

Answer (score 1):

at first you need to make class for a table, like this:

```cs
class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

second, add class name in your context model, like this

```cs
class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Post> Post { get; set; }
}
```

third, in console or package manager you must make a migration,

```sh
add-migration makePostTabale
```

and after that update database:

```sh
Update-Database
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! If you have added a new table in SQL server,not in VS 2017, what method should be used?

Comment: you can use `.Net Core CLI` (command-line interface). use ```dotnet ef migrations add makePostTabale``` for make migration and ```dotnet ef database update``` for updating database from migration. for more info see [MS Doc Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this cmd:

Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Force